# Hide duplicate row in VF using Javascript

Tags: javascript, pageblocktable

I'm trying to remove duplicate rows in Visualforce using Javascript. For now, I have to do it on the UI because the underlying logic is a mess. On the bright side I'm trying to explore the use of JS.

So, here is the present output of a VF page...

[image: Present]
I'm trying to get this output...

[image: Required]

Here is the javascript and the VF page with only a single column to avoid confusion as I need to remove duplicates according to the first column containing 7 digits:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#test column').filter(function() {
            var text = $(this.cells[0]).text();
            return $(this).prev('column').filter(function() {
            return $(this.cells[0]).text() === text;
        }).length;
       }).remove();
      </script>
```

and the VF...

```
            <apex:pageblocksection title="Details" showheader="true" collapsible="true" columns="1" >
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!gp.inv}" var="i" id="test">   
            <apex:column colspan="7"> 
                    <apex:facet name="header">INo.</apex:facet>
                    <apex:outputLink value="/apex/IList?id={!i.invoices__r.id}"><apex:outputText value="{!i.invoices__r.invoice_no__c}"/></apex:outputLink>
                </apex:column>
```

With this JS, there is no change in VF output. I have tried it out on HTML  and it works fine, but unable to replicate on VF. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Does the JS console display any error?

Comment: Use mean the Dev console?

Comment: The browser javascript console, not the SF dev console.

Comment: Remember that Visualforce prefixes ID values and and you won't find a "column" element in the HTML output. So your jQuery selector "#test column" will not match anything. Use you browser's "Inspect Element" feature to see the HTML that Visualforce generates; that is the environment that the JavaScript is operating in.

Comment: @geekymartian Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined vfpage:81(anonymous function) vfpage:81
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CACHE_MISS

Comment: Thanks @KeithC Do you mean these kind of ids   j_id0:j_id2:j_id3:j_id4:0:j_id69:test ?

Comment: Yes. You can put id values on all the parent elements or use jQuery's "ends with" matching of `$("[id$='test']")`. Matching by class instead is cleaner IMHO. It also sounds like you haven't correctly referenced the jQuery code either.

Comment: as @Keith pointed out first you need jQuery loaded, then you start to worry about the DOM traversing.
I really encourage you to try to filter the collection from APEX, doing it with JS is not a good idea.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just check these values in a controller, as opposed to doing it on the page? You said its a visualforce page, this means you should be able to attach a controller.

Comment: Let me explain why I don't want to use APEX. I have a order object that has order lines, invoice lines as child objects. But I need to display the invoice header which doesn't have a direct relation with Orders. So my query follows as... Order(parent)>invoice lines(child)>invoice(parent)>name. If I have multiple invoice lines for a order of single invoice, I get the same Invoice name for all the invoice lines. So I was seeking the help of javascript.